# Typedef static std::list array

Tags: c++

Why is this not working:

```
        enum Color {
            enRed,
            enGreen,
            enYellow
        };

        typedef static std::list<Apple> Basket[3];

        std::for_each(Basket[enRed].begin(),
                      Basket[enRed].end(),
                      std::mem_fn(&Apple::Name())
                      );
```

Am i cooking up trouble here?

Edit: Ops, yes i mistyped, it should be enRed and not Color for the index

Comment: `typedef` defines a type alias, not a variable.

Comment: there is so many thing wrong with this piece of code.

Comment: Don't use names like `enRed` borrowing `en` from `enum`. Borrowing letters from keywords is a red flag, even if MFC does it. Descriptive names are better: `color_red` or in C++11, `Color::red`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`static` can only be applied to an instance, `typedef` is used to declare a `type` so this statement can not work:

```
typedef static std::list<Apple> Basket[3];
```

Although you could create a `typedef` and than later on declare a `static` instance of it. You can not use `Color` as an index since it is a `type`, although the following would work:

```
Basket[enRed]
```

Comment: @Potatoswatter It is indexing into an array of `std::list`, or at least my modified version is but I am pretty sure that was the intent

Comment: Ok, i now understand where i am going wrong. I did not know that static only applied to an instance. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In your code `Color` is

> type name given to the enumeration

It can't be used for indexing.

Comment: @icktoofay `Color` is not a value.

Comment: Yes i mistyped, it should be enRed and not Color for the index. Thank you for pointing that out.